# How to sum up multiple Inputs multiplied by value simultaneously

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So, I have  [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/737v3qxr/1/)  where I have a table that has an input and a cost. It also has a bit of jquery.

```
$( ".total" ).change(function() {
    i = 1;
var input001 = document.getElementsByName(i)[0];
var cost001 = document.getElementById("cost" + i);
var total001 = input001.value * cost001.innerHTML;
 var num = total001;
 var total = num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "1,");
  document.getElementById("printchatbox").value = total;
  i++;
});
```

This code multiplies the first input times the first Item Cost. I would like to find a way to repeat this 45 times (one for each item) without copy and pasting this code 45 times... If that is the only way to do it, I can do that... but I'm hoping to learn something and make my code significantly shorter at the same time. This table is generated by php, I just copied and pasted the html that was generated for the fiddle.

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $row['ItemID'] = ltrim($row['ItemID'], '0');
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number" class="total" name="<?php echo $row['ItemID']?>" value "<?= isset($_POST[$row['ItemID']]) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST[$row['ItemID']]) : "" ?>"></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['ItemID']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['ItemDescription']?></td>
                <td id="<?php echo 'cost' . $row['ItemID'] ?>"><?php echo $row['ItemCost']?></td>
                <td id="<?php echo 'value' . $row['ItemID'] ?>"><?php echo $row['ItemValue']?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </table>
```

this is the PHP code on the website that creates the table... 
this is the first row of the html table.

```
<tbody><tr>
                 <td><input class="total" name="1" value="" ""="" type="number"></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Barrel Wrap 47"x31"</td>
                <td id="cost1">39.38</td>
                <td id="value1">47.25</td>
            </tr>
```

and here is an image of the first 10 rows of the table.

[image: first ten rows of the table]

if I have to change something in there, that is totally fine, I'm just hoping to keep the readability and reduce the redundancy.

Thanks

Comment: give us a small section of what the final table looks like. (on the browser without the php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/737v3qxr/2/

So I've changed a few things:

```
$( ".total" ).change(function() {
    var name = this.name;
  var quantity = this.value;
    var cost = document.getElementById("cost" + name).innerHTML;
    var total = quantity * cost;
  items[name] = {cost, quantity}
    new_total();
});
```

when you apply a function/listener to something, the `this` references the element itself, so you didn't need to do an extra i and i++ with it.

I've also introduced JSON (it's basically a dictionary in any other language), which helps with tracking prices.

Most of the code is just renamed since your logic wasn't actually too far off, just very clumsy and convoluted.

I've also added a `new_total` function, which doesn't really need to be a function in and of itself, but it's just my preference.

Finally I've added an id to your total to make it easier to track.

`<input id="total" type="text" readonly id="printchatbox" name="total">`

There's also some weird empty text which I'm assuming refers to your php, but you will have to deal with that yourself.

`<input class="total" name="45" value="" ""="" type="number">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event handler argument as well:

```
$( ".total" ).change(function(e) {
    var cost001 = document.getElementById("cost" + e.target.name);
    var total001 = e.target.valueAsNumber * Number(cost001.innerHTML);
    var prev = Number(document.getElementById("printchatbox").value);
  document.getElementById("printchatbox").value = total001 + prev;
});
```